# Where i am doing wrong with find_one(collection, query) method implemented using predefined method of pymongo find_one() created in Databse class?

Tags: python, oop, flask, pymongo

I was learning flask, and as the trend is the first application taught is a Blog application, So i have implemented a Database class to implement various methods of pymongo api. Various methods has been defined in the Class as shown in the [Implementation of Database Class and Query Outputs of find_one() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnCvd.png). All other methods created are working well, but facing issue with **find_one(collection, query)** it always return none value, no matter whether database have entry or not. But, the predefined method of API return correct data. Where i am doing wrong?

```
import pymongo
class Database:
    URI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
    DATABASE = None

    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(Database.URI)
        Database.DATABASE = client['BBloger']

    @staticmethod
    def insert(collection, data):
        Database.DATABASE[collection].insert(data)

    @staticmethod
    def remove(collection, query):
        Database.DATABASE[collection].remove(query)

    @staticmethod
    def find(collection, query):
        Database.DATABASE[collection].find(query)

    @staticmethod
    def find_one(collection, query):
        Database.DATABASE[collection].find_one(query)
```

I am using version **0.12.2** method of **Flask** and **3.6.0** version of **PyMongo**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is resolved, i forget that by default any python method return None value, which i was getting as output. The modified code will be:

```
import pymongo
class Database:
    URI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
    DATABASE = None

    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(Database.URI)
        Database.DATABASE = client['BBloger']

    @staticmethod
    def insert(collection, data):
        Database.DATABASE[collection].insert(data)

    @staticmethod
    def remove(collection, query):
        Database.DATABASE[collection].remove(query)

    @staticmethod
    def find(collection, query):
        return Database.DATABASE[collection].find(query)

    @staticmethod
    def find_one(collection, query):
        return Database.DATABASE[collection].find_one(query)
```